# Why Jenkins 'readYaml' pipeline utility step is ignoring duplicate keys in YAML?

Tags: java, jenkins, yaml, jenkins-pipeline, snakeyaml

I am reading a YAML file using the Jenkins pipeline utility step [`readYaml`](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-utility-steps/#readyaml-read-yaml-from-files-in-the-workspace-or-text):

```yaml
key1:
  subkey1: val1
key2:
  subkey2: val2
key2:
  subkey2: val3
```

I noticed that the step is ignoring the duplicate keys in the YAML and throws no exception. When I looked into the [source code](https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-utility-steps-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/org/jenkinsci/plugins/pipeline/utility/steps/conf/ReadYamlStep.java) I could not see any relevant configuration.

This plugin is using the `snakeyaml` library. By default the `snakeyaml` library [allows duplicate keys](https://bitbucket.org/snakeyaml/snakeyaml/src/master/src/main/java/org/yaml/snakeyaml/LoaderOptions.java?at=master#LoaderOptions.java-24) as per the `LoaderOptions` class.

If the Jenkins pipeline utility step is not changing the `LoaderOptions` config then why the duplicate key is being ignored?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The YAML specification does not allow multiple keys.

The `snakeyaml` loader option `allowDuplicateKeys=true` means it will silently ignore any duplicate keys and not throw an exception.

See: https://github.com/snakeyaml/snakeyaml/blob/c98ffba9cd065d1ead94c9ec580d8b5a5966c9d3/src/main/java/org/yaml/snakeyaml/constructor/SafeConstructor.java#L124

Comment: See also the comments here: "Default behavior is to allow duplicate keys and use the last key value as it was before." https://bitbucket.org/snakeyaml/snakeyaml/issues/337/option-to-disallow-duplicate-keys

Comment: This topic of duplicate keys in YAML (why there's no exception) was also quite discussed regarding the role of a yaml parser (a "responsibility" for data) in these threads (btw. a developer of SnakeYaml is directly responding to this kind of questions + the approach taken by the parser).
- https://groups.google.com/g/snakeyaml-core/c/M-TRKg-0-F4 OR https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/1683#issuecomment-59194846 . 
Maybe it's "too much info" but could be interesting to get a context that was generally taken into account when dealing with duplicate keys.